# KubernetesAPIにルートCA証明書を登録したい

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes

物理サーバー上にmicrok8sでkubernetes環境を構築しています。
環境内にdocker registryポッドを立て、その中からカスタムイメージをKubernetes内に直接プル・デプロイするためにkubernetes APIでtls通信を行う必要ができました。
そのためCAサーバーとしてstep-caポッドを立ててdocker registryに証明書を自動発行する環境は出来たのですが、その一方Kubernetes APIがCAのルート証明書を参照できるようにする方法が分かりません。

以下のドキュメントは読んだのですが、状況は近いものの登録したいのはCAのルート証明書なため応用できずにいます。
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.3", GitCommit:"816c97ab8cff8a1c72eccca1026f7820e93e0d25", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-01-25T21:25:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23+", GitVersion:"v1.23.4-2+98fc2022f3ad3e", GitCommit:"98fc2022f3ad3e02b6b6e01f0a87c0975d41207e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-02-23T14:54:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

step-caバージョン

```
smallstep/step-ca:0.18.1
```

docker registry バージョン

```
registry:2.8.0
```

デプロイ時ログ

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled         66s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned develop/load-custom-img-dep-76d545bc7-ktsmz to myhost
  Normal   Pulling           26s (x3 over 65s)  kubelet            Pulling image "192.168.1.31:30050/custom-image:latest"
  Warning  Failed            26s (x3 over 65s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "192.168.1.31:30050/custom-image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.1.31:30050/custom-image:latest": failed to resolve reference "192.168.1.31:30050/custom-image:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.1.31:30050/v2/custom-image/manifests/latest": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed            26s (x3 over 65s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff           13s (x4 over 64s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "192.168.1.31:30050/custom-image:latest"
  Warning  Failed            13s (x4 over 64s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

証明書の登録方法の他、SSL/TLSについてもまだ理解が浅いため理解・手法の間違い等ありましたらご指摘いただければと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your ssl validation!
see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72546045/getting-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error-while-verifying-c

Comment: スタックオーバフローへようこそスタックオーバー関連のサイトで同じ回答であったとしても、リンク紹介だけにとどまらず、ぜひ日本語で回答してみてください